# asking for help factoring SQL code - MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

SQL Fiddle is currently down regarding MS SQL Server code, so here is a dropbox link to a .txt containing the DDL to create the schema I'm using:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6si4r37449q3ajb/DDL.txt?dl=0

I'm studying for an exam and I know there's a more efficient way to code this, I just don't know what it is.

**5.    Find out the department which has the highest number of personal computers installed.**

```
select top(1) pc.location, count(pc.location) as number_of_comps_in_dept
from pc
group by location
order by number_of_comps_in_dept desc
```

My code featured above works, but what if I wanted to just get the department name (labeled location in this case)? I can't really call a single value back via my current code - which isn't friendly to procedures, functions, and triggers down the road.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why not just remove the other columns from your `SELECT`statement?

Comment: How would I go about doing so? The currently selected columns are providing variables for an aggregate function. I'm pretty sure I need them.

Comment: If you think you need them then it is time to learn SQL basics. No, you do not need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the other columns in your `SELECT` statement. However, you need to replace the column in the `ORDER BY` clause with the aggregate:

```
select top(1) pc.location
from pc
group by location
order by count(pc.location) desc
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/482867)</kbd>

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know you could use order by in combination with an aggregate. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use result from subquery to get depratment name only

```
SELECT Dept_with_Max_Computers
FROM
(
select top(1) pc.location Dept_with_Max_Computers, count(pc.location) as number_of_comps_in_dept
from pc
group by location
order by number_of_comps_in_dept desc
) Z
```